# extract nonzero values of a matrix and display as a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

[image]

I tried to code it but I don't know where to start guys.

Comment: Please post your attempt at the solution as this will help anyone in understanding where any difficulties at solving this problem came from.

Comment: *I tried to code it but I don't know where to start guys.* What have you tried so far? Edit your question and add your attempt there.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me like a relatively dumb MATLAB homework, especially because

1. the hint is to use two for loops and an if statement that you don't really need, and
2. it is oblivious to the fact that [MATLAB is column-major](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491555/why-if-matlab-is-column-major-do-some-functions-output-row-vectors).

Anyway... If the 2D array `U` is defined as follows

```
U = [3 5 0 0 2 1;...
     0 9 0 0 0 6;...
     0 0 5 0 0 0;...
     9 8 4 5 2 6;...
     0 0 0 0 0 0;...
     3 5 0 0 0 0];
```

and you want to create a row vector `F` that holds all the nonzero values of `U` (collected row-wise), here are two possible approaches:

### Using `reshape` and logical indexing

```
F = reshape(U.', [1, prod(size(U))]);
F = F(F ~= 0);
```

### Using `nonzeros` (more efficient)

```
F = nonzeros(U.').';
```

### Naive approach: using two for loops and an if statement

(I'll leave this approach as an exercise until you demonstrate some effort towards finding a solution...)

Comment: I love you said it was "dumb homework".  +1.  I also don't see why two `for` loops are required when other efficient algorithms exist.

Comment: @rayryeng The only inefficiency I can think of in my approaches is the transposition, but I don't know whether there is a way around that...

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it as you already know MATLAB naturally works in column major when the assignment wants a row vector as you have also mentioned at the beginning of your post. Again, "dumb homework" :)!

Answer (score 1):

It's Christmas, so I suppose I can write the answer using the naive approach with the two `for` loops and `if` statement.  Be advised that Jubobs provided you more thorough and more efficient answers to achieve the same task, but I'm assuming you are starting out learning MATLAB and I won't shy away from anyone who wants to learn it!

The hint is pretty self-explanatory.  You need two `for` loops - one to traverse the rows and one to traverse the columns.  You'd have to access each element in the matrix and use an `if` statement to check to see if the element is not equal to zero.  Should it be so, you would add the element to the vector `F`.

As such, with this approach, `F` would initially be empty because we don't know what the final size of the vector would be.  Therefore, you'd do something like this:

```
F = [];
for r = 1 : size(U,1)
    for c = 1 : size(U,2)
        if U(r,c) ~= 0
            F(end+1) = U(r,c);
        end
    end
end
```

The code essentially goes through every single element in your matrix and checks to see if the element is non-zero.  If it is, then **append** this element to `F`.  The `end+1` is important because `end` is a special keyword in MATLAB that accesses the **last** element of your array.  By doing `end+1`, we are telling MATLAB that we want to add **one more element** to the end of the array.  This code will allow `F` to grow as we start adding in non-zero elements into `F`.  However, you will probably get a warning when putting this into the MATLAB editor.  Specifically, MATLAB will ask you to [preallocate your array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html#f8-793781) to improve performance.  This is because if you add additional space on top of your array, this will slow down performance whereas if you allocate the right amount of space, you're not needlessly increasing space.  However, because the amount of elements in `F` is small, then there won't be any significant performance gains if you use the above code.

FWIW, this is the output of `F` when using `U` defined in your example:

```
>> format compact
>> F
F =
     3     5     2     1     9     6     5     9     8     4     5     2     6     3     5
```

---

Good luck, and happy learning!

Comment: Plus one for "It's Christmas" :)